# Java - How do you take user input using ActionListener, process it, then output it on another Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I've been told that ActionListeners are not meant to return value, but in that case, how do I pass user input from one Java GUI to another?

For example, what if I want to do this?

1. Create menu A that allows users to choose which food they want using JCheckBox.
2. User clicks on "Finish" JButton on menu A and the window closes.
3. The system takes the input and opens another window, displaying the food the customer has chosen plus the food's corresponding images.

I have problem with Step 3 because whatever input the user chooses in menu A, the ActionListener will not let me transfer it to anywhere else.

The only way I can think of to work around this problem is to continue to finish everything inside the ActionListener, but that seems unlikely to be the most effective solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: implement a constructor for your second window, which takes the value from the checkbox as parameter and pass it in the actionPerformed

Comment: You provide all the data to your controller, your controller performs the action *in its own thread* and changes its model, your controller then notifies the view to create a new window. The new window reads the model and shows it.

Comment: That s is where the "model" in model-view-controller comes into play, basically, you design a model which is shared between the various elements of you program and use an observer pattern to generate events when the model is updated

Comment: I think he dont know about MVC and Observer Design patterns, He is creating simple project , ??